# Alguien sabe como puedo hacer un filtro de información?

Tags: c#, xml

estoy generando un XML a base de otro pero al momento de generar los NumUnIdenPol me repite muchos valores y quiero que únicamente me imprima los datos sin que repitan.

El trabajo se está haciendo en C# estoy ocupando únicamente eso y el XML base.

Alguien sabe alguna forma en la que pueda hacer algun tipo de filtro?

```
#region XmlReader
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"C:/Users/Ismael Can/Desktop/TSP191206KT8202112XC.xml");      
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("UsingXmlWriter.xml");

xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PLZPolizas");          
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlnsPLZ","http://www.sat.gob.mx/esquemas/ContabilidadE/1_3/PolizasPeriodo");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlnsxsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xsischemaLocation", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/esquemas/ContabilidadE/1_3/PolizasPeriodo http://www.sat.gob.mx/esquemas/ContabilidadE/1_3/PolizasPeriodo/PolizasPeriodo_1_3.xsd");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.3");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("RFC", "XXAX010101AAA");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Mes", "12");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Anio", "2020");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("TipoSolicitud", "AF");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NumOrden", "ABC1234567/88");

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(path);

while (xmlReader.Read())
{
   if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "AuxiliarCtas:DetalleAux"))
   {
      if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
      {
         string IdPoliza = xmlReader.GetAttribute("NumUnIdenPol");

         xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PLZPoliza");
         xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NumUnIdenPol", IdPoliza);
         xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

      }                                      
   }
}

xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
xmlWriter.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
}
#endregion
```

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Realiza el recorrido para obtener tu primera medalla y de paso ves cómo es la dinámica del sitio, preguntas que dicen "no he investigado nada y tampoco he intentado algo, ¿qué hago?, ¿por dónde empiezo?" tienden a ser ignoradas. 3. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Esto te ayudará a mejorar las preguntas incrementando el % de obtener respuestas 4. Intenta colocar en el buscador de tu agrado "C# Filtro XML", también intenta en el buscador de SOes, seguramente algún otro desarrollador ha pasado por algo similar o por lo mismo.

Comment: Por cierto, el recorrido es el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Sería más fácil eliminar duplicados utilizando XSLT o XQuery o LINQ. Tienes archivos muy largos o ¿por qué utilizas XmlReader/XmlWriter?

Comment: si el Archivo xml de donde estoy sacando la información es algo extenso y por eso estoy utilizando xmlReader seria mas sencillo si utilizo esos que mencionas?